# Does PayPal Payments Advanced support requiring payment (subscribe button)?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Is it possible to provide a subscribe button (subscription) on a website with PayPal Payments Advanced without leaving the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You "keep customers on your site for the entire checkout process". Technically, there is an iframe that surfs to PayPal, but the customer is not aware of this. This is a good thing, because PayPal is already PCI compliant, and trust me you don't want to apply for that.

[Source](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced)